# concrete floor self leveling

Tags: concrete

I have concrete floor that has sunk about 1 1/2 IN from the center from  the sides walls some pare of it has vinyl on it . Do I have to remove the vinyl before ussing compound.How can I level this and what compound should I use . Thanks

Regards

Ali

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's a bit tough to understand what you're asking; you might want to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the vinyl. The leveling compound should go on top of the bare concrete.
But before you do anything: check if the foundations are okay. If the floor isn't properly supported, the added weight from the leveling compound will make the floor subside faster.